# JW Player (version 5) fails to play video streamed by PHP

Tags: php, jwplayer

When I try to play video (streamed by PHP application), JW Player 5 returns following error:

> > The Queue failed at step 5: Playlist could not be loaded: Playlist file did not contain a valid playlist

Player setup:

```
jwplayer('container_id').setup({
  'flashplayer' => valid Flash player URL,
  'file' => link that will output a valid video content,
  'width' => 640,
  'height' => 360,
});
```

Player downloads the entire video file, and than displays the error. When I put a link to the same video file stored on Amazon S3, video plays correctly. Because of that, my assumption is that combination of headers that application sends when serving files is causing JW Player to think it is a playlist, not a video file.

Headers that server returns:

```
Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Length  28169930
Content-Type    video/mp4
Date    Thu, 07 Nov 2013 14:36:46 GMT
Expires Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=80
Pragma  no-cache
Server  Apache/2.2.24 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.4.17 mod_ssl/2.2.24 OpenSSL/0.9.8y
Set-Cookie  …
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.4.17
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Make sure whether server enabled with Apache gzip compression, in that case, just disble it and try. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-jw-player-plugin-for-wordpress-playlist-could-not-be-loaded-xml-could-not-be-parsed-or-playlist-was-empty

Comment: This has to do with the player not knowing what kind of file this is. See my answer below, it should fix the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under:

```
'file' => link that will output a valid video content,
```

Add:

```
'provider': 'video',
```

This will fix the problem.